# REST API Design - What to do with repeating data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am new to REST API Development. I am building an API to fetch all harvests of a farmer. Farmer table has a primary key farmer_id. The Harvest table has a primary key harvest_id and a foreign key to Farmer Table. I am using this query to get harvest data.

```
public List<Harvest> getFarmerHarvests(Long farmerId) {
        String jpql = "SELECT h FROM Harvest h WHERE h.farmer.farmerId = :farmerId";
        TypedQuery<Harvest> query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, Harvest.class);
        query.setParameter("farmerId", farmerId);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

This is what the result set looks like

```
[
    {
        "harvestId": 1,
        "cropName": "Barley",
        "farmer": {
            "username": "don_joe",
            "firstname": "Don",
            "lastname": "Joe",
            "password": "$2a$10$l0ExQAoGIdk.ULksc/W66eXEqWelt3Jo9Il7aPgJM7LE0G9Ok2Dnm",
            "email": "don.joe@example.com",
            "address": "123 Main Street",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "phno": "+1 1234567890",
            "enabled": true,
            "farmerId": 1
        },
        "harvestDate": "2023-12-23T18:30:00.000+00:00",
        "expiryDate": "2023-12-31T18:30:00.000+00:00",
        "quantity": 10,
        "units": "Kg (Kilograms)",
        "pricePerQuantity": 100,
        "smallestUnitSize": 1,
        "imageUrl": "no url"
    },
    {
        "harvestId": 2,
        "cropName": "Wheat",
        "farmer": {
            "username": "don_joe",
            "firstname": "Don",
            "lastname": "Joe",
            "password": "$2a$10$l0ExQAoGIdk.ULksc/W66eXEqWelt3Jo9Il7aPgJM7LE0G9Ok2Dnm",
            "email": "don.joe@example.com",
            "address": "123 Main Street",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "phno": "+1 1234567890",
            "enabled": true,
            "farmerId": 1
        },
        "harvestDate": "2023-12-23T18:30:00.000+00:00",
        "expiryDate": "2024-02-29T18:30:00.000+00:00",
        "quantity": 30,
        "units": "Kg (Kilograms)",
        "pricePerQuantity": 300,
        "smallestUnitSize": 1,
        "imageUrl": "no url"
    }
]
```

As you can see, the farmer information is repeated in both the objects. What is the best practice? Is this how the data should be in an API response ? Or should I be excluding this data? If so, how do I exclude it?

For my usecase, I don't require the Farmer data on every object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the design of your JSON response to model the One-to-Many relationship as opposed to the Many-to-One relationship.

For example:

```
{
  Farmer: Bob,
  Harvests: [
    { Harvest: 1 },
    { Harvest: 2 }
    ...etc
  ]
}
```

Consider the following SQL query that has a one-to-many Author to Posts relationship, in which when the author is queried, all posts belonging to them are returned in a nested array.

```sql
SELECT 
    Authors.author_id,
    Authors.author_name,
    array_agg(Posts.post_content) AS posts
FROM 
    Authors
JOIN 
    Posts ON Authors.author_id = Posts.author_id
WHERE 
    Authors.author_id = 'specific_author_id'
GROUP BY 
    Authors.author_id;
```

It is essentially the same structure with farmers having many posts.

Comment: Oh ok. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I have added this to my Farmer Entity -
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "farmer")
    private List<Harvest> harvests;

But now, every time I fetch the Farmer details, all the Harvests will be included along with it. How can I exclude, or include it only when required.

Comment: This depends on your function implementation and API design. There's a thousand approaches that could be used. That said, you could look for a ?include=harvests query param (or any custom name param), you could set up 2 different endpoints, and so on.

Comment: If I was designing this API, I'd make 2 endpoints, getFarmer and listHarvests. listHarvests would accommodate filter params, such as the farmer_id. getFarmer would require a farmer_id. Then on getFarmer, I'd supply an optional parameter to include a named relationship (like Harvest), and then handle the SQL query according to that params presence in the handler function. However, if this is just a single endpoint for a quick project, the best approach is the one that works and you can write fast 